# Hot to get clean polygons in R after st_combine/st_union with sf package?

Tags: r, r-sf

I have a tidy dataset for census sectors in sf format ([setores_sp_ok.rda](https://github.com/bruno-pinheiro/app_acesso_saude/raw/master/data/setores_sp_ok.rda)), which has polygons for two different territorial models, indicated by variable `modelo`. I want to aggregate census sectors by `modelo` and `cnes`, to create another dataset with new boundaries.

I can do this using `group_by()` + `summarise()` technique, which automatically uses `st_union()` to aggregate polygons. But the result is poor, with many internal boundaries.

```
# load packages
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(lwgeom)

# import data
load(url("https://github.com/bruno-pinheiro/app_acesso_saude/raw/master/data/setores_sp_ok.rda"))

# combine polygons
ubs_malhas <- setores_sp %>% 
  st_make_valid() %>% 
  group_by(cnes, modelo) %>% 
  summarise(area = sum(area)) %>% 
  ungroup()

# plot
ggplot(ubs_malhas[ubs_malhas$modelo == "vigente", ]) +
  geom_sf(lwd = .2)
```

[image: result have many internal boundaries]

I know that is possible to realize this kind of operation combining `st_combine`, `st_union` and `st_intersect`, but I'm not realizing how to make it.

How to combine polygons by `modelo` and `cnes` and get clean aggregated polygons, without internal boundaries?

Someone has any tip?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Your data may be tidy in a tidyverse sense, but the geometries certainly aren't. The borders between the "vigente" modelo units don't quite line up in many cases, hence you get these little "leftovers" caused by gaps between units. I would snap those to a grid of, say 1cm, and then call `st_union`.

```
# load packages
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(lwgeom)

# import data
load(url("https://github.com/bruno-pinheiro/app_acesso_saude/raw/master/data/setores_sp_ok.rda"))

# combine polygons
ubs_malhas <- setores_sp %>% 
  st_snap_to_grid(size = 0.01) %>%
  st_make_valid() %>% 
  group_by(cnes, modelo) %>% 
  summarise(area = sum(area)) %>% 
  ungroup()

# plot
ggplot(ubs_malhas[ubs_malhas$modelo == "vigente", ]) +
  geom_sf(lwd = .2)
```

In case you still have unwanted polygons left, you may have to increase the grid size or delete those manually, e.g. in QGIS or thelike.

Comment: Thank you @TimSalabim. Trying this results, for me, in "Error in CPL_snap_to_grid(x, origin, size): st_snap_to_grid: not supported in this version of liblwgeom". I'm on a Debian 9 with all packages updated. My `lwgeom` package is version 0.1.4. Do you have any idea why this?

Comment: Yes, I had the same problem. You need to compile the package from source with `R CMD INSTALL lwgeom --configure-args="--without-liblwgeom"` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/r-spatial/lwgeom#linux)

Comment: Not working yet. When i pass this on terminal, returns "Warning: invalid package ‘lwgeom’ Erro: ERROR: no packages specified"

Comment: Yeah, it's a little tricky... download the zip archive from the github site, unpack and rename the folder contained in the zip from `lwgeom-master` to `lwgeom`. Then running `R CMD INSTALL lwgeom --configure-args="--without-liblwgeom"` from the terminal at the location of the lwgeom (not inside it) folder should work.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add `sfheaders::sf_remove_holes()` after your summarise function.

```
ubs_malhas <- setores_sp |> 
  st_make_valid() |>
  group_by(cnes, modelo) |>
  summarise(area = sum(area)) |> 
  sfheaders::sf_remove_holes() |>
  ungroup()

ggplot(ubs_malhas[ubs_malhas$modelo == "vigente", ]) +
  geom_sf(lwd = .2)
```

Alternatively, you can also use `nngeo::st_remove_holes()` instead of `sfheaders::sf_remove_holes()`

Answer (score -1):

The function

```
    nngeo::st_remove_holes(your_sf_object)
```

Solve your problem.